# Detect both falling and jumping in sprite kit game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite

I am working on a sprite kit/swift game. I want the ball to do different things when it falls and jumps. Now if it falls it also uses the code at the bottom (the code for jumping)

Here is the code I am using:

```
override func collisionWithBall(ball: SKNode) -> Bool {

        if ball.physicsBody?.velocity.dy < 0 {
            ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: ball.physicsBody!.velocity.dx, dy: 500.0)

            if platformType == .Normal {
                self.removeFromParent()
            }

            if platformType == .Break {
                self.removeFromParent()
                ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: ball.physicsBody!.velocity.dx, dy: 800.0)
            }
        }
        if ball.physicsBody?.velocity.dy > 0 {
        if platformType == .Break {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(1, forKey: "nextValue")
            self.removeFromParent()
            ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: ball.physicsBody!.velocity.dx, dy: -800.0)
        }
        }

        return false
    }
```

If it jumps I want it to only use this **if ball.physicsBody?.velocity.dy > 0** And when it falls I want to only use this **if ball.physicsBody?.velocity.dy < 0**.

What can I do to make it working?

Comment: you need to do else if,,  for your dy > 0 or return inside your if.  Other wise your velocity is < 0, then you change it to 500, which is > 0, and you fall into the second condition

Comment: Thank yo very much. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have do change the if statements to use an `else if` for the second condition. Like this:

```
if ball.physicsBody?.velocity.dy < 0 {
    // Handle falling here...
} else if if ball.physicsBody?.velocity.dy > 0 {
    // Handle jumping here...
}
```